# How to test a constructor in Junit test?

Tags: java, junit4

How to test this Fraction constructor in Junit4 test case?
Thank you!

```
public class Fraction {

    private int num;
    private int den;

    public Fraction(int num,int den){
        this.num=num;
        this.den=den;
        if(den==0){
            this.den=1;
            System.out.println("ERROR: DENOMINATOR CAN NOT BE 0");
            System.out.println("Now the fraction is changed to"+toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use System.out to signal a problem. And you shouldn't change the value of the denominator either. Throw an IllegalArgumentException instead. That will hide the original bug (passing 0) by transforming it into a more subtle one, harder to detect. Imagine such a line of code in a program detecting if you have a cancer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd run the constructor and then check the denominator holds the value you expect:

```
public class FractionTest() {
    private Fraction f;

    @Test
    public void testLegalConstruction() {
        f = new Fraction (4, 7);
        assertEquals ("wrong num", 4, f.getNum());
        assertEquals ("wrong den", 7, f.getDen());

    @Test
    public void testIlegalConstruction() {
        f = new Fraction (3, 0);
        assertEquals ("wrong num", 3, f.getNum());
        assertEquals ("wrong den", 1, f.getDen()); // Note the 1
}
```